# How do I make dot product of two matrices and then cross product with the third matrix？

Tags: numpy, matrix

I have tried many ways but it does not work
for example:

```
a = np.mat([1, 2, 3])
b = np.mat([4, 5, 6]).T
c = np.mat([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print(a * b * c)
```

ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (2,2) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

or:

```
a = np.mat([1, 2, 3])
b = np.mat([4, 5, 6]).T
c = np.mat([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print(np.dot(a, b) * c)
```

ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (2,2) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

or:

```
a = np.mat([1, 2, 3])
b = np.mat([4, 5, 6]).T
c = np.mat([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print(np.array(a * b) * c)
```

ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (2,2) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

or:

```
a = np.mat([1, 2, 3])
b = np.mat([4, 5, 6]).T
c = np.mat([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print((a * b)[0][0] * c)
```

ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (2,2) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

Comment: Try to forget about `mat`, use `@` for dot product and be happier.

Comment: @gboffi: I agree with you that `@` can help a lot to simplify code one should keep in mind that `@@` does not work and you need at least python 3.5 (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/).

Comment: With `np.mat`, results are always 2d, and `*` is `np.dot`.  `np.cross` is the cross product, but might not be what you want.

Comment: I have tried and I can not get used to `np.array`. There are too many confusions. I might as well go back to use `mat`.

Comment: This is a comment by Nathaniel Smit, in the _Numpy-discussion_ mailing list "_I do have the sense that when people choose to use it_ [`np.mat`], _they eventually 
come to regret this choice. It's a bit buggy and has confusing 
behaviours, and due to limitations of numpy's subclassing model, will 
probably always be buggy and have confusing behaviours. And it's 
marketed as being for new users, who are exactly the kind of users who 
aren't sophisticated enough to recognize these dangers._"

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it:

```
a = np.mat([1, 2, 3])
b = np.mat([4, 5, 6]).T
c = np.mat([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print(np.dot(a,b)[0,0]*c)
print((a*b)[0,0]*c)
```

`np.dot(a,b)` gives you a 1x1 matrix, thus you need 2 indices to convert it to a scalar.

Comment: is there any difference between (a*b)[0][0] and (a*b)[0, 0]? I thought they were the same in python

Comment: I have found the answer, thank you! It really helps. I have google it all day!

Answer (score 0):

With `np.matrix`, all 3 arrays are 2d, (1,3), (3,1) and (2,2):

```
In [3]: a
Out[3]: matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
In [4]: b
Out[4]: 
matrix([[4],
        [5],
        [6]])
In [5]: c
Out[5]: 
matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])
In [6]: a*b
Out[6]: matrix([[32]])
In [7]: _.shape
Out[7]: (1, 1)
```

The matrix product `np.dot(a,b)`, also expressed as `a*b` for this type, is also 2d (1,1).  Where possible matrix operations preserve the 2d nature of the class.

So all your attempts to do a further matrix product with the (2,2) shaped matrix run into the same problem.

One way around this is to pull out the single element with indexing:

```
    In [8]: np.dot(a,b)[0,0]*c
Out[8]: 
matrix([[ 32,  64],
        [ 96, 128]])
```

This is the same as `np.dot(np.dot(a,b)[0,0],c)`, but with a scalar it's the simple elementwise multiplication.

I thought we could do elementwise multiplication  of two matrices with `c.multiply(...)`, but apparently that method is only defined for `scipy.sparse` matrices.  (I'm seeking the equivalent of MATLAB `a .* b`). (see edit below)

### arrays

If these variables had been defined as `np.array`, or if we convert them with:

```
In [25]: a.A1              # shortcut for to array followed by ravel
Out[25]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [26]: b.A1
Out[26]: array([4, 5, 6])
In [27]: c.A
Out[27]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

The `dot` product of 2 1d arrays produces a scalar (see `np.dot` docs):

```
In [28]: np.dot(a.A1, b.A1)
Out[28]: 32
```

It's trivial to multiply an array by a scalar:

```
In [29]: np.dot(a.A1, b.A1)*c.A
Out[29]: 
array([[ 32,  64],
       [ 96, 128]])
```

I could also have used the 2d array versions of `a` and `b`:

```
In [34]: np.dot(a.A, b.A)
Out[34]: array([[32]])           # 2d array result

In [35]: np.dot(a.A, b.A) * c.A
Out[35]: 
array([[ 32,  64],
       [ 96, 128]])
```

This works because the array `*` is elementwise, and a (1,1) array can broadcast with a (2,2) array  (see the `numpy` docs on broadcasting).

Trying to do the dot product of a (1,1) with (2,2) runs into the same problem as before: `np.dot(np.dot(a.A, b.A), c.A)`

The `dot @` operator can be used as:

```
In [37]: a.A1@b.A1*c
Out[37]: 
matrix([[ 32,  64],
        [ 96, 128]])
```

but we still need to understand how `np.array` vs. `np.matrix` work and how dimensions interact.

### `np.cross`

The subject line mentions `cross product`.  That's something quite different, and implemented in `np.cross`:

```
In [31]: np.cross(a.A1, b.A1)
Out[31]: array([-3,  6, -3])
```

### `np.multiply`

`np.multiply` does (broadcasted) element-wise multiplication, the `*` of regular `ndarrays`:

```
In [48]: np.multiply(a,b)
Out[48]: 
matrix([[ 4,  8, 12],
        [ 5, 10, 15],
        [ 6, 12, 18]])
```

It can handle the (1,1) produced by `np.dot(a,b)`,

```
In [49]: np.multiply(np.dot(a,b),c)
Out[49]: 
matrix([[ 32,  64],
        [ 96, 128]])
```